# Upgrade from Eclipse Mars to Photon on Ubuntu cause problems

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-mars, eclipse-photon

Hi I am wondering if anyone found some similar issues upgrading from ubuntu machine.
I upgraded from eclipse mars to eclipse photon and when I try to run my Tomcat 8 server I get the following error.

```
Plug-in "org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.TomcatLaunchConfigurationDelegate". org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.TomcatLaunchConfigurationDelegate.allowAdvancedSourcel
```

I have tried updating all repo's to no success, I read some threads about WTP ServerTools so I tried upgrading to version 3.10 and this will not update for me either, any ideas would be grateful.

Or should I just do a reinstall to the version I had working, would properly save time in the long run

Comment: Neon and above require Java 8. Are you at least using Java 8? For both Tomcat and Eclipse? Have you looked at the logs for more complete error messages and stack traces?

Comment: yes I am using Java 8 at the moment, I have checked the logs and noting is there, everything is pointing me to wtp plugin that photon must use version 3.10.x but I am having issues installing, thank you for your response I have installed a different version and I am working through it today

Comment: How did I you do this upgrade?

Comment: it upgraded when I did a apt-get upgrade in ubuntu, I have uninstalled all of eclipse and reinstallled IDE, from my research it seems plugins are the issue, I am back up and running on my new IDE, thanks for your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having the same issue. I upgraded from within eclipse (Oxygen) by entering the new repository location.

Java 8 / Ubuntu 18.04

I then couldn't start tomcat with the above noted error.

I just ran apt update & apt dist-upgrade but it didn't pull down any relevant packages.

I then ran the 'Help | Check for Updates' option in eclipse and it installed some wtp tool updates. I then deleted the Server instance in eclipse and re-created it.

Tomcat now starts correctly.

Summary:
Run 'Help | Check for Updates' in eclipse and it looks like that will fix your problem.