# After Eclipse upgrade from Oxygen to Photon Tomcat 8 no longer starting

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, tomcat8, eclipse-oxygen, eclipse-photon

This question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51137867/8521895) except for the Eclipse "upgrade from" version, mine was Oxygen to Photon not Mars, and for the platform my office tends to use Windows, so I am on Win7.

After upgrade, Tomcat8 would no longer start, I removed the server and then added it back. I even tried removing the configurations files: `org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs` and `org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs` still not starting, publishes fine, just not starting.

Here are the "Event Details":

```
Plug-in: org.eclipse.equinox.registry

Message: Plug-in "org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.TomcatLaunchConfigurationDelegate".

Stack Trace:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.TomcatLaunchConfigurationDelegate.allowAdvancedSourcelookup()V
at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.TomcatLaunchConfigurationDelegate.<init>(TomcatLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:38)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:187)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:931)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:60)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchDelegate.getDelegate(LaunchDelegate.java:83)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:738)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:717)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:712)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.startImpl2(Server.java:3566)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.startImpl(Server.java:3502)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$StartJob.run(Server.java:377)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:60)
```

Again I realize this is similar to [Jason's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6950020/jason-delaney) question but I do not have enough `reputation` to expand or add similar details on his question. Looks like he just reinstalled, I was hoping not to do that.

Yes, both Eclipse and Tomcat8 configured for Java 8, upgraded via the IDE.

I'm sure I have to upgrade something just not sure what that is, thanks for reading.

**Update:**
Sorry for delayed update, I wound up reinstalling Photon from scratch, then just reopened my projects, all worked well. Wished I had seen [@John Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10046817/john-gordon)'s answer prior, I would have tried that first, sounds quite feasible.

[@nitind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27905/nitind)
I assumed I did when I did the upgrade, I definitely did not upgrade things like *"Java Development Tools"* specifically.

[@John Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10046817/john-gordon)
I never even considered the *"Apache Tomcat Plugin"* meh...

Comment: Do you have all of the available updates installed, including the latest Java Development Tools?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  Was able to resolve it by simply upgrading my Apache Tomcat Plugin (9.1.2).

Answer (score 0):

It happened the same with me, in my case I had to do a new download of a clean version of eclipse Photon instead of updating.

And it worked with the same version of java and tomcat it used in the eclipse Oxygen.

One small problem was that I had to install all the plugins again in the new version of eclipse. (SVN, Dark theme, Sonar lint and etc.)